# Are @interface and @end always necessary in .h file?

Tags: objective-c

I noticed a strange thing in sample code downloaded from apple dev center. the sample code is Footprint: Indoor Positioning with Core Location. There is no @interface and @end in AAPLMKMapRecRotated.h file. But it works well in simulator. Can anyone explain why? Thanks!

Comment: because the class looks having ANSI-C code only, not Objectice-C.

Answer (score 0):

"@interface" and "@end" are necessary wherever you want to declare the interface to an Objective-C class. If you don't declare the interface of an Objective-C class in your header, it's obviously not needed. If you declare interfaces of three Objective-C classes in your header, you'll need it three times. If you declare the interface of an Objective-C class in a .m file, so nobody outside that file can see it, then you put it into the .m file.

Answer (score 0):

@interface ... @end declare a ObjC class.. Not all .h file nor all Apple API rely on ObjC, a lot of C is used thorough their framework (CoreAudio, CoreMidi, CoreGraphic, GrandCentralDispatch...) in those framework .h file are classic C header used as such and therefore no @interface .. @end...